# How do I access Waterline models from grunt tasks?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, gruntjs, sails.js, waterline

**TL;DR** - How do I use my Waterline models from within a grunt task, in a sails project?

I am attempting to create some grunt tasks within a Sails project to process a CSV file and insert data into a Postgres database. I was hoping to use Waterline for this, though was unsuccessful in connecting to the database.

I was wondering, how would I use my Waterline models from within a grunt task?

I am not overly sure of what Sails does behind the scenes to make my models accessible, though I would be very interested in understanding.

I will update in the morning with example code of what I have tried.

Comment: Coming to this from a PostgreSQL background, it's like buzzword-soup. Sails, Grunt, Waterline, huh? Without code and errors it's not really possible to respond to this usefully even if I did have a clue about the tools you were using though.

Comment: Grunt, like Rake, is a task runner. When running a Sails server the Sails CLI takes care of registering your Waterline models, and making them globally accessible. 

I would like to use the Waterline models to interact with Postgres from within a grunt task, though was unable to because I am unaware of what sails is doing behind the scenes.

I believe if you understand the tools I am talking about the question is fairly straight forward. How do I use my Waterline models from within a grunt task, in a sails project?

I will add code examples now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was more expressing bewilderment than asking for anything though. The Node and Rails communities both produce new tools (with cryptic names) at a rate that's quite astonishing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was importing things wrong. The following works properly :

```
var CWD = process.cwd();
var path = require('path');

var Waterline = require('waterline');
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend(require(path.join(CWD, 'api/models/User')));

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('seedDb', 'Given a list of addresses, assign long and lat.', function (clinicCsv, outputCsv) {
        // tell grunt this task is async
        var done = this.async();

        // create ORM
        var orm = new Waterline();
        orm.loadCollection(User);

        // initialize ORM
        orm.initialize({
            adapters: {
                'sails-postgresql': require('sails-postgresql')
            },
            connections: require(path.join(CWD, 'config/connections')).connections,
            defaults: require(path.join(CWD, 'config/models')).models
        }, function (err, ontology) {
            if (err) throw err; 

            console.log(ontology.collections);
            done();
        });
    });
};
```

Where api/models/User is :

```
module.exports = {
  identity: 'User',
  connection: 'localPostgresqlServer',

  attributes: {
    firstName: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: 'sting'
    },
    email: {
        type: 'email'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string'
    }
  }
};
```

And config/connections and config/models are in the standard Sails format. The key was specifying the connection within the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get away with doing it like this

```
grunt.registerTask('seedDb', 'Given a list of addresses, assign long and lat.', function (clinicCsv, outputCsv) {
    // tell grunt this task is async
    var done = this.async();

    require('sails').load({
        hooks: {
            blueprints: false,
            controllers: false,
            cors: false,
            csrf: false,
            grunt: false,
            i18n: false,
            logger: false,
            policies: false,
            pubsub: false,
            request: false,
            responses: false,
            session: false,
            socket: false,
            views: false
        }
    }, function(err, app){
        // access to models, do your magic here

        done();
    });
});
```